# Where are the bags generally stored on an airliner?

Tags: baggage-handling-system

I don't mean carry on bags. What I mean is where are the locations of the non carry on bags on an airliner. Also does it depend on the airliner of where the bags are stored.[image]Source:(gokaysarioz.com)

Comment: Related: [How is the cargo hold volume for passenger aircraft designed?](//aviation.stackexchange.com/q/8936)

Answer (score 9):

In smaller aircraft, the baggage is put directly inside the cargo hold.

[image: Baggage]

Source: jacksonville.com

In case of larger aircraft, the baggage is put inside the conformal cargo container or the unit load device, which is then placed inside the cargo hold.

[image: Baggage container]

Source: roger-wilco.net

[image: Cargo hold]

Source: supath.net

Answer (score 6):

On a modern large airliner (particularly for long haul), the bags are loaded into a [ULD (Unit Load Device)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_load_device) which are the big silver boxes that you see on airport ramps. These ULDs are then loaded into the cargo hold of the aircraft, which is located directly below the passenger deck.

Here is a photo of the empty cargo hold of an A320 [(source)](https://www.atsb.gov.au/publications/investigation_reports/2009/aair/ao-2009-034.aspx):

[image]

And this is what it looks like in cross-section after loading (this is an A300) [(source)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Airbus_A300_cross_section.jpg):

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't strictly say "a modern airliner" always uses ULDs. Plenty of commercial transport aircraft fresh from the factory today are bulk loaded up to and including members of the 737 and A320 family, especially in the US. And brand new RJs will be bulk loaded too.

Comment: @ZachLipton: Good point, I'll clarify.

Comment: Don't think there are any belly cans for narrow body a/c. AKE's won't fit. They're bulk loaded.

Comment: Certain A320 aircraft have been ordered by carriers at build with a CLS - Cargo Loading System - Due the size of the hold space, there is a specific Unit Load Device that is manufactured for this aircraft - LD3-45 - the 45 signifying the height of the ULD that is compliant with the A320. A Standard LD3 as used on the Wide Body Types is 64 inches in height